# Get sleep or Get to sleep?

Tags: phrases

I can accept if **get to sleep** is correct according to [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20to%20sleep). However, I wonder if get sleep is OK to use because I've seen people using **get sleep** on the internet.  Or are they different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean two very different things.

**Get *to* sleep** means to *reach the state of being asleep*, that is, to transition from "being awake" to "being asleep." Here "sleep" metaphorically refers to a *location* that you get *to*, which really means it is a state of being that you enter.

**Get sleep** has the sense of *acquire [some] sleep*, that is, *to posses an amount of sleep*, meaning "be asleep for some time." The word "sleep" is used as a quantifiable *thing* that you can have more or less of. You will almost always see some quantifier between the two words: "some," "a lot," "a little," "not much," etc.

So you can say:

> I didn't **get much sleep** last night; I couldn't **get to sleep** until two in the morning.